# Trying to insert null data into a view in SQL, any other way?

Tags: sql-server, database, view, null

Part1 on View
1-1) Create a view named VDept_Headcount that reports headcount for each department.
The report includes 3 columns as follow:
Dept_Name, Dept_Number, No_Emp.
Include all the departments.
Show the content of the view through SQL (Select * from  VDept_Headcount;)

```
USE COMPANY
GO

--1-1) Create a view named VDept_Headcount that reports headcount for each department.
CREATE VIEW VDept_Headcount(Dept_Name, Dept_Number, No_Emp)
AS
SELECT d.DNAME, d.DNUMBER, COUNT(e.DNO) 
FROM DEPARTMENT d LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEE e ON e.DNO = d.DNUMBER
GROUP BY d.DNAME, d.DNUMBER;
GO

SELECT *
FROM VDept_Headcount;



USE COMPANY

GO

--Add yourself into Employee
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE
VALUES('Dan', NULL, 'Chan', '122345687', '13-Nov-1948', '323 Williams Ct, Columbus, OH', 'M', 55000, '987654321', 5);

SELECT *
FROM VDept_Headcount;
```

My question is there a different way to replace null value if I want add things back in? Can I use a blank value?

Comment: Seems like you need one triggers ,`after delete` and `after update`

Comment: Is that what you need ? after you detect if it's an insert or delete you can do the insert.

Comment: You can join to chat room no need to email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should detect if it's an `INSERT` OR `DELETE` , try this :

```
CREATE TRIGGER AuditEmp_Trigger
ON YOUR_TABLE
AFTER INSERT , DELETE
AS
  if (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INSERTED ) > 0 AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DELETED) =0
     BEGIN
       INSERT INTO destination_table SELECT * FROM INSERTED;
     END
  if (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INSERTED ) = 0 AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DELETED) >0
     BEGIN
        INSERT INTO destination_table SELECT * FROM DELETED;
     END
GO
```

If you need to check just the `columns updated` you can use [`COLUMNS_UPDATED ()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms186329.aspx#Syntaxe)

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger needs to be able to handle **multiple rows** in the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo table, since if your `UPDATE` statement affects 10 rows, the trigger is called **ONCE**, but these pseudo table contain 10 rows each. You cannot just try to "select" the values from those table - you'd get **one arbitrary row**, and all other would be ignored and not handled.

You need to write your triggers in a **set-based** fashion, and in the case of `UPDATE`, join the two pseudo tables on the **primary key** of the table they're attached to:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.EMPLOYEE_FKDno_UPDATE 
ON dbo.DEPARTMENT FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Audit_Emp_Record (date_of_change, old_Lname, new_Lname, old_dno, new_dno, old_ssn, new_ssn)
        SELECT
            GETDATE(), d.Name, i.Name, d.Number, i.Number, d.Mgr_Ssn, i.Mgr_Ssn
        FROM
            Inserted i
        INNER JOIN
            Deleted d ON i.PrimaryKey = d.PrimaryKey
```

In case of the `DELETE`, you'll just have only the `Deleted` table with the "old" values - so you'll need something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.EMPLOYEE_FKDno_DELETE
ON dbo.DEPARTMENT FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Audit_Emp_Record (date_of_change, old_Lname, new_Lname, old_dno, new_dno, old_ssn, new_ssn)
        SELECT
            GETDATE(), d.Name, NULL, d.Number, NULL, d.Mgr_Ssn, NULL
        FROM
            Deleted d
```

And in case of the `INSERT`, you'll just have only the `Inserted` table with the new values - so you'll need something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.EMPLOYEE_FKDno_DELETE
ON dbo.DEPARTMENT FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Audit_Emp_Record (date_of_change, old_Lname, new_Lname, old_dno, new_dno, old_ssn, new_ssn)
        SELECT
            GETDATE(), NULL, i.Name, NULL, i.Number, NULL, i.Mgr_Ssn
        FROM
            Inserted i
```